# Populate table with random data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables as following.

'Areas' Table

```
|    AreaKey      |    AreaID    |
|-----------------|--------------|
| <identity/int>  |  <varchar>   |
```

'Readings' Table

```
|    ReadingKey   |      AreaKey      |   Reading   |    ReadingDateTime   |
|-----------------|-------------------|-------------|----------------------|
| <identity/int>  |<FK:AreaKey-Areas> |   <float>   |      <datetime>      |
```

- 'AreaKey' in Readings table is a foreign key to 'AreaKey' of Areas table.

Areas table already have some data with row id's ranging from 1 to 50.

I want to populate the Readings table with some sample data - (random float values for 'Reading' column between 1.0 and 100.0  AND a random datetime value for ReadingDateTime between a given DateTime range; for example between current datetime and a datetime 3 months back).  These values should be inserted to the Reading table by **randomly** selecting AreaKeys which already exist in the Areas table.

In other words I want to insert random reading values to randomly selected areas, with random datetimes.

Can anyone give me a clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Areas table has 50 records, with row ids 1-50, I would just look into using the `RAND` function.

Something like this seems to work:

```
SELECT ROUND(((50 - 1 -1) * RAND() + 1), 0) as AreakKey,
    ROUND(((100 - 1 -1) * RAND() + 1), 1) as Reading,
    DATEADD(mm,-3,GETDATE()) +
(
ABS(
    CAST(
        CAST( NewID() AS BINARY(8) ) AS INT
    )
)
%
CAST(
    (GETDATE() - DATEADD(mm,-3,GETDATE())) AS INT
    )
) as ReadingDateTime
```

And here's some [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7855).

Good luck.

Comment: Worked exactly as I needed. Saved a lot of time for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: forgive my knowledge, where is the insert statement ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at [RedGate's SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/)?  RedGate tools have been a total boon for our company.

Tool recommendations aside, just write a quick application that:

1. generates a list of keys for your Area table
2. inserts some randomized records into your Area table
3. inserts some randomized records into your Readings table, picking random elements from the list of keys you created in step #1

Comment: Third party tools are not an option for me! Thanks for the reply anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NEWID() and select the results into a temp table. Please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx

```
Select column into #temp from table
order by NEWID()
```